# FullCalendar locale not setting button labels and firstDay

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

According to [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale), setting the `locale` property should translate header buttons and set the `firstDay` property, among others.

But this simple JS snipped ([codepen](https://codepen.io/maxxer/pen/vYVGErv)) will be displayed with Sunday as first day of week.

Some strings are translated, like month name and weekdays.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    locale: "it",
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug? Is it maybe because I'm including the library from a cdn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself by looking at the [*Locale Demo*](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo): the core JS is missing locale data, adding the URL below to the HTML made localization behave correctly.

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.5/locales-all.global.min.js

I'm rather new to FC and I found puzzling the missing of JS files into releases zip files.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. Just a note: this line must be added **AFTER** the one which retrieves `index.global.min.js`; otherwise, it will emit the "FullCalendar is not defined" error.